# Using PHP to create an excel file with multiple worksheets

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have 2 or more files generating a table:

File: my_table_0.php

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Previews</th>
        <th>Sizes</th>
        <th>ShapeName</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //connection to mysql
    mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass"); //server , username , password
    mysql_select_db("db");

    //query get data
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table0 WHERE ShapeName='value' ORDER BY Sizes ASC ");
    $no = 1;
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$data['Previews'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['Sizes'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ShapeName'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

File: my_table_1.php

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Previews</th>
        <th>Sizes</th>
        <th>ShapeName</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //connection to mysql
    mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass"); //server , username , password
    mysql_select_db("db");

    //query get data
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ShapeName='value' ORDER BY Sizes ASC ");
    $no = 1;
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$data['Previews'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['Sizes'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ShapeName'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

And my file who makes the xls is like this:

File: make_xls_with_sheets.php

```
<?php
// The function header by sending raw excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// Defines the name of the export file "filename.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=all_tables.xls");

// Add data table to first worksheet
include 'my_table_0.php';

// Add data table to next/another worksheet
include 'my_table_0.php';
?>
```

This file inserts both tables in same worksheet...i like it to
make a new worksheet in same xls-file for every table, is that
possible?

Comment: Is a third party script an option? If so I have some very good experience with https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel which can create a new worksheet - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md Maybe that will get you somewhere.

Comment: While MS EXcel can import html markup, it isn't a native format Excel file, and doesn't support options for "multiple worksheets"... for that, you need to generate a native format (BIFF of OfficeOpenXML) spreadsheet file using any of the many available PHP libraries capable of that

Comment: Thanks alot Taff, i've tried it but i couldn't get it to work by adding a table from a .php file?

Comment: @mark-baker Do you have any idea please?
I really need the xls file for later use in another program.

Comment: @CyPro - Yes, I have ideas..... I'm the developer of the [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).... and I'd suggest that the best way isn't to use HTML markup at all, but to populate the PHPExcel object directly from the database resultset

Comment: @mark-baker Now i got it to work and im using PHPexcel, thanks alot! But now i have another problem, when i make my PHPexcel file i have like ALOT tables with pretty much data in it but it will only add data to my 9 first tables the rest is only filled with headings :-( anyone seen that problem?

Comment: Without seeing any code, I can't guess at the problem, I don't know what your code is doing

Comment: @Mark-Baker - Check here please: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e5hr34tp/)